# ta.lowest() and ta.highest() functions are returning only NaN

Tags: function

I can't get ta.lowest() and ta.highest() to give me anything other than NaN. I'm trying to write a script to look at the most recent 100 bars and draw a line through the mode price. The logic requires I find the highest and lowest prices among those 100 bars. After debugging I've finally narrowed it down to the aforementioned functions. I made a separate, simplified script (below) to see if the functions were working, by just having the highest and lowest prices printed as a string on the last bar, and I still get NaN. I have no idea what could be wrong.

Edit: This is pine script in trading view. Sorry for not specifying. I thought this forum was for pine script only. I was directed here from the trading view website by clicking on the "pine script Q&A button". Thank you for replying to me.

I just came back to this and found the solution: I had to remove the 'var' keyword from the variable declarations.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Min and Max Price", overlay=true)
var int lookBackPeriod = 100
var float minPrice = ta.lowest(low, lookBackPeriod)
var float maxPrice = ta.highest(high, lookBackPeriod)
if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, text="Min Price: " + str.tostring(minPrice),color=color.green)
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high - 1, text="Max Price: " + str.tostring(maxPrice),color=color.purple)
```

Comment: What is the "ta" object? What language are you writing in? What libraries are you using? There is not enough information in your question for us to be able to help you. Please edit your question to improve it.